# Does Azure Batch support .Net Core in Azure Data Factory v2?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I've been trying to get even a simple "Hello World" .Net Core 2.x Console App running via ADF v2 Custom Activity/Batch Service but with no luck. It does seem to work when I provision a WindowsServer and run a .Net Framework 4.5.x Console App though. Can't find any examples where this would work but also can't imagine why it wouldn't.

I've tried calling:

1. ConsoleApp.dll
2. dotnet run ConsoleApp
3. and dotnet publish -r win-x64, then copying those files over and calling ConsoleApp.exe

Any suggestions on what else I could try?

Comment: Hiya, can you please elaborate what you mean by `I've been trying to get even a simple "Hello World" .Net Core 2.x Console App running via ADF v2 Custom Activity/Batch Service but with no luck. It does seem to work when I provision a WindowsServer and run a .Net Framework 4.5.x Console App though.` **i.e. are you saying that it works on windows server but not in other O/S Distros?**

Comment: I think he/she means that .Net framework (exe) works but Core (dotnet xxx.dll) does not work with the Windows Server images in Batch. I have the same problem and trying to figure it out how to push dotnet core installation into the Windows Server image.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we had our dotnet core application that was parsing the files, so we ended up scaling up Azure Function to P1V2, and that did the job for us both CPU and RAM wise. So, if it is your code that you need to run, try Functions. In addition, Functions are serverless which eliminates a lot of pluming. That is unless you have a specific need to run it as Batch.